# Javascript var case sensitive

Tags: javascript, servicenow

Firstly I will start with a disclaimer. I am new to javascript.

This javascript is for ServiceNow.  It is to stop certain staff members from raising a catalog item.  It is working, however if a user was to use a capital, it would allow it.

I would like to make the script case insensitive.

I use a variable to define the email address:

```
var deny = "@email.com.au";
```

and then the variable is used in an if statement.

```
if (email.indexOf(deny) >= 0){
            g_form.showFieldMsg('variable', "email.com.au is not accepted" , 'error');
            g_form.setValue('variable',"");
```

How does one do this?

Cheers

Comment: Using [toLowerCase](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_tolowercase.asp)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can convert email to lowerCase and check index

```
if(email.toLowerCase().indexOf(deny) >= 0){
        g_form.showFieldMsg('variable', "email.com.au is not accepted" , 'error');
        g_form.setValue('variable',"");
```

Comment: Hey LD, Thanks that worked perfectly.  Im going to look up the toLowerCase() as it makes no sense to me right now.

Comment: Ok I get it now.  makes sense :)

Answer (score 0):

Try the javascript function [tolowercase](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_tolowercase.asp) and then do an indexof

Answer (score -1):

Take the email array and convert all the content to lowercase using

```
for (int i = 0;i < email.length;i++) {
    email[i] = email[i].toLowerCase();
}
```

Then Compare

Comment: This is the same mistake I made. `email` isn't an array, it's the input that's being checked.

Comment: Oh then just ignore this

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to comment, I appreciate it :)